# Ignore POM in 3rd party JAR

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, artifactory

I have uploaded a 3rd party JAR file to my Artifactory repository. This JAR file contains a POM, but the pom is only valid inside the 3rd-parties build environment.

When I attempt to build a project that uses this JAR, I get errors because it is looking for a parent project that we don't have access to.

I understand from [this post](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) that this is because the POM is being read from inside the 3rd party Jar.

Is there a a way to edit the POM of *our* project to tell Maven to ignore the pom of this 3rd party Jar?

(as a workaround, I can remove the POM from the Jar - this fixes the issue, but I would prefer not to have to remember to do this on every release of this 3rd-party component).

Please also note that I am very new to Maven, so use short words and long explanations ;-)

Comment: Does it still extract the POM in the JAR when you provide the details on the command line as the first example of [the mentioned post](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) shows?

Comment: You can use scope attribute in dependency and set it to provided. This attribute makes the jar to be omitted while packaging which has to be taken care manually.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan I don't think that helps me - I am using classes from that JAR file, so my code will not compile if Maven cannot obtain it! (Some of the 3rd party JARs are actually set to provided as we know they will exist in the target system - it doesn't help resolve the problem in the question unfortunately)

Comment: @SanderVerhagen But then I would have to supply the JAR manually to any developer/build system that required it, which defeats the main purpose of using Maven in the first place! I want Maven to be able to obtain it from Artifactory - ideally without having to edit anything other than the POM of our application.

Comment: I'm unclear of how much this artifact is in your control. If it is, define a parent POM that's not "secret".

Comment: @SanderVerhagen It's a 3rd party artifact that is not under our control whatsoever - the only thing I can do to it is edit the contents of the JAR (but I would prefer not to have to do that as previously explained).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix it is to deploy the parent pom to Artifactory. That's how Maven works.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, but we do not have access to the parent POM. It is used internally by, and is proprietary to, the 3rd party.

Comment: Just make one up - you know the GAV.